# The elements of {$1,2,3,...,n$} and {$1,2,3,...,n$} are randomly paired. What is the probability distribution of $S=\text{sum of pair products}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, correlation

The elements of {$1,2,3,...,n$} and {$1,2,3,...,n$} are randomly paired. What is the probability distribution of $S=\text{sum of pair products}$ ?

For example, say $n=5$. There are $5!$ ways to pair the elements, for example $(1,3)\ (2,5)\ (3,1)\ (4,4)\ (5,2)$ which gives $S=(1)(3)+(2)(5)+(3)(1)+(4)(4)+(5)(2)=42$.

I know that, in general:
$S_{\text{min}}=\sum_{k=1}^n{(k)(n-k+1)}=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(n+2)$, the [triangular pyramidal numbers](https://oeis.org/A000292).
$S_{\text{max}}=\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2}=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$, the [square pyramidal numbers](https://oeis.org/A000330).

I suspect that the probability distribution of $S$ is well-documented but I don't know what it's called.

Context: In 2020, the [IB](https://www.ibo.org/) cancelled exams due to the pandemic and gave grades (1-7) based on other factors (predicted grades, coursework, school's historical grades). When the results were released, some schools felt that some of the grades seemed random. Then I wondered, if seven students got random Math grades 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and random Physics grades 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, what is the probability distribution of the [correlation coefficient](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CorrelationCoefficient.html) between Math grades and Physics grades? That is essentially my question here, except my question here is generalized for $n$ students and grades.

Comment: I conjecture that for large $n$ it tends to get (slowly) concentrated  around the mean $\frac{n(n+1)^2}4$, as the standard deviation seems to grow as $n^{5/2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, the distribution is well-documented.

Arrange [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A175929) into rows by cutting through pairs of consecutive 1's.

$$1$$
$$1\ 1$$
$$1\ 2\ 0\ 2\ 1$$
$$1\ 3\ 1\ 4\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 4\ 1\ 3\ 1$$

$$...$$

Divide the numbers in the $n^{\text{th}}$ row by $n!$. For example, the $4^{\text{th}}$ row becomes

$$\frac{1}{24}\ \frac{3}{24}  \frac{1}{24} \frac{4}{24} \frac{2}{24} \frac{2}{24} \frac{2}{24} \frac{4}{24} \frac{1}{24} \frac{3}{24} \frac{1}{24}$$

These are the probabilities that $S=S_{\text{min}},\  S_{\text{min}}+1,\ S_{\text{min}}+2,\ ...,\ S_{\text{max}}$, respectively.

Here is a [graph](https://oeis.org/A175929/graph) related to the distribution.

It seems there is no simple formula for the probabilities.

I found the sequence by using an [online permutation generator](https://calculla.com/permutations_generator), excel, and [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

(The sequence is based on work done by the late John Conway in 1993. Professor Conway was my teacher in 1993. Little did I know that he would still be "teaching" me 29 years later.)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the mean at least.
Write all the permutations of $(1,\ldots n)$ in $n!$ rows:

```
1, 2,   3, ...,   n-1, n
1, 2,   3, ...,   n,   n-1
...
n, n-1, n-2, ..., 2,   1
```

Then you would need to multiply the first column by $1$, the second row by $2$... the last column by $n$, sum everything up and divide by the number of rows $n!$.

But if you consider just the first column, since every two numbers are interchangeable, each number appears exactly $n!/n=(n-1)!$ times. The same is true for every column. So the total sum:
$$
n!\bar S = \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n}}_{\text{sum by cols}} \left(k\cdot\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n} i(n-1)!}_{\text{sum by elements in a col}}  \right) = (n-1)!\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\right)\left(\sum_{k=i}^{n} i\right) =\\
(n-1)!\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2,\\
\bar S = \frac{n(n+1)^2}4
$$

Comment: Yes, I found the same expression for $\bar{S}$ by realizing that $S$ must have a symmetric distribution, and then finding the mean of $S_{\text{min}}$ and $S_{\text{max}}$.

Comment: By curvefitting I found the variance was $\sigma^2=(n+1)^2n^2(n-1)/144$

Comment: @Empy2 You are right (and I deleted to avoid confusion, thank you), it should be $$\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^niX_i=\sum_{i=1}^ni\mathbb EX_i=\mathbb EX_1\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac14n(n+1)^2$$